# Conditional probability among $n$ dependent random variables

Tags: probability, correlation

Suppose there is a random variable $\omega \in \{1,0\}$ with $\Pr (\omega
=1)=q\in (0,1).$ There are $n$ agents each of whom receives a noisy signal $%
s_{i}\in \{1,0\}$ about $\omega $. The precision of each signal is $\Pr
(s_{i}=\omega |\omega )=\gamma >\frac{1}{2}$. The pairwise conditional
correlation between any two signals is $\operatorname{Corr}\left(s_{i},s_{j}|\omega \right)=\rho \in
\lbrack 0,1]$.

My questions are how do I calculate (i)
\begin{equation*}
\Pr (s_{1}=1,s_{2}=1,...s_{i-1}=1,s_{i+1}=1,...s_{n}=1|s_{i}=0,\omega =1),
\end{equation*}
i.e., what is the probability that $n-1$ other agents receive $s=1$
conditional on the fact that agent $i$ receives $s_{i}=0$ and the state is $%
\omega =1?$

(ii) More generally, what is the probability that $n_{1}$ agents receive $s=1
$ and $n_{2}$ agents receive $s=0$ conditional on the fact that $n_{3}$
agents receive $s=1$ and $n_{4}$ agents receive $s=0$, and the state is $%
\omega =1$ such that $n_{1}+n_{2}+n_{3}+n_{4}=n?$

Comment: I want to come back and write a more thorough answer but I will say that 1) use the standard formula that $P(A|B)=P(A\cup B)/P(B)$ and 2) there are several models for the joint distribution for correlated Bernoulli random variables that allow interactions of various orders. One good option for this problem might be a multivariate Bernoulli distribution with only second order (pairwise) interactions.